# basic spring gwt application on Cloudfoundry hangs on loading screen

Tags: gwt, spring-roo, cloud-foundry

I deployed a very simple Spring ROO Java (6) app using GWT and HSQL/Hibernate to Cloudfoundry. It is deployed and running but when accessed, the browser window simply states "Loading" and seems to hang indefinitely. It runs fine locally via Maven goal 'gwt:run'.

FYI, I had already built a similar app the same way only using MVC instead of GWT and it is deployed and running fine. The MVC app utilizes several HSQL tables.

I have reduced the GWT app to a single table containing a single field and still cannot get it to display. Any suggestions on where to start looking?

Comment: Since I can't answer my own question:

Comment: Well, I found my own answer, posted on the Springsource website:

Thread: how to deploy a gwt project to tomcat? 
http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?105346-how-to-deploy-a-gwt-project-to-tomcat

Answer (score 1):

Question was answered by user asking the question: "Well, I found my own answer, posted on the Springsource website: Thread: how to deploy a gwt project to tomcat? http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?105346-how-to-deploy-a-gwt-project-to-tomcat"